# Getting and printing random value as string from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

get a random string value from a `JavaScript` array.

```
var randomcity = ["Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Ağrı"," Aksaray", "Amasya", "Ankara", "Antalya", "Ardahan", "Artvin", "Aydın", "Balıkesir", "Bartın", "Batman", "Bayburt", "Bilecik", "Bingöl", "Bitlis", "Bolu", "Burdur", "Bursa", "Çanakkale", "Çankırı", "Çorum", "Denizli", "Diyarbakır", "Düzce", "Edirne", "Elazığ", "Erzincan", "Erzurum", "Eskişehir", "Gaziantep", "Giresun", "Gümüşhane", "Hakkâri", "Hatay", "Iğdır", "Isparta", "İstanbul", "İzmir", "Kahramanmaraş", "Karabük", "Karaman", "Kars", "Kastamonu", "Kayseri", "Kilis", "Kırıkkale", "Kırklareli", "Kırşehir", "Kocaeli", "Konya", "Kütahya", "Malatya", "Manisa", "Mardin", "Mersin", "Muğla", "Muş", "Nevşehir", "Niğde", "Ordu", "Osmaniye", "Rize", "Sakarya", "Samsun", "Şanlıurfa", "Siirt", "Sinop", "Sivas", "Şırnak", "Tekirdağ", "Tokat", "Trabzon", "Tunceli", "Uşak", "Van", "Yalova", "Yozgat", "Zonguldak"];

var random;

function generateRandom () {
    random=Math.floor(Math.random * randomcity.length);
    console.log(random.value);
    document.getElementById('newInputBox1').value=random;
}
```

a new `InputBox` generated with id: 'newInputBox1'.

I get value from the user via a prompt and cannot insert it into this generated box

Comment: The random picking of the array element is working?

Comment: No, it doesn't come as a string, it comes as a number.

Comment: Then why are you not describing this in your question? `document.getElementById('newInputBox1').value=randomcity[random]`

Answer (score 3):

A small change to your code should make everything work nicely.

We'll get a `randomIndex` using Math.random() then use it as an index to the input array.

We'd wrap this up in a `getRandomElement()` function and pass the randomcity array to it:

```js
const randomcity = ["Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Ağrı"," Aksaray", "Amasya", "Ankara", "Antalya", "Ardahan", "Artvin", "Aydın", "Balıkesir", "Bartın", "Batman", "Bayburt", "Bilecik", "Bingöl", "Bitlis", "Bolu", "Burdur", "Bursa", "Çanakkale", "Çankırı", "Çorum", "Denizli", "Diyarbakır", "Düzce", "Edirne", "Elazığ", "Erzincan", "Erzurum", "Eskişehir", "Gaziantep", "Giresun", "Gümüşhane", "Hakkâri", "Hatay", "Iğdır", "Isparta", "İstanbul", "İzmir", "Kahramanmaraş", "Karabük", "Karaman", "Kars", "Kastamonu", "Kayseri", "Kilis", "Kırıkkale", "Kırklareli", "Kırşehir", "Kocaeli", "Konya", "Kütahya", "Malatya", "Manisa", "Mardin", "Mersin", "Muğla", "Muş", "Nevşehir", "Niğde", "Ordu", "Osmaniye", "Rize", "Sakarya", "Samsun", "Şanlıurfa", "Siirt", "Sinop", "Sivas", "Şırnak", "Tekirdağ", "Tokat", "Trabzon", "Tunceli", "Uşak", "Van", "Yalova", "Yozgat", "Zonguldak"];

function getRandomElement(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

function generateRandom () {
   document.getElementById('newInputBox1').value = getRandomElement(randomcity);
}

generateRandom();
```

```html
<label>Result: </label><input id='newInputBox1' value = ''/>
<button type='Button' onclick='generateRandom()'>Generate Random</button>
```

Comment: Thank you to each and every one of you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the commented code below, as a candidate solution for your problem

```js
 const randomcity = [
            "Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Ağrı", " Aksaray", "Amasya", "Ankara", "Antalya", "Ardahan", "Artvin", "Aydın", "Balıkesir", "Bartın", "Batman", "Bayburt", "Bilecik", "Bingöl", "Bitlis", "Bolu", "Burdur", "Bursa", "Çanakkale", "Çankırı", "Çorum", "Denizli", "Diyarbakır", "Düzce", "Edirne", "Elazığ", "Erzincan", "Erzurum", "Eskişehir", "Gaziantep", "Giresun", "Gümüşhane", "Hakkâri", "Hatay", "Iğdır", "Isparta", "İstanbul", "İzmir", "Kahramanmaraş", "Karabük", "Karaman", "Kars", "Kastamonu", "Kayseri", "Kilis", "Kırıkkale", "Kırklareli", "Kırşehir", "Kocaeli", "Konya", "Kütahya", "Malatya", "Manisa", "Mardin", "Mersin", "Muğla", "Muş", "Nevşehir", "Niğde", "Ordu", "Osmaniye", "Rize", "Sakarya", "Samsun", "Şanlıurfa", "Siirt", "Sinop", "Sivas", "Şırnak", "Tekirdağ", "Tokat", "Trabzon", "Tunceli", "Uşak", "Van", "Yalova", "Yozgat", "Zonguldak"
        ]
        var randomCityIndex;
        var element;
        var divElement;

        function generateRandom() {
            //Get the elements by ID
            element = document.getElementById('newInputBox1');
            divElement = document.getElementById('div');

            // Get the index of Random City
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomcity.length);
            
            // Set the value for input tag as el.value = randomValue
            element.value = randomcity[rand];

            // For other type of tags like div and p, use el.innerHtml or el.innerText = randomValue
            divElement.innerHTML = randomcity[rand];
            
        }
```

```css
 #div, p {
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 5px auto;
            background-color: burlywood;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random City</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Random City
</h1>
<button onclick="generateRandom()">Random City</button>
In Input: <input id="newInputBox1"/>
<p>Random City in div:</p>
<div id="div">{Click the button to see RandomCity}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ali hocam teşekkürlerimi sunar iyi günler dilerim.

Comment: rica ederim ve iyi günler :)

Answer (score 1):

Something is missing in your code. Here down i can explain your mistake

**1.** You forget to add round bracket `()` after `Math.random`

**2.** You can not linked your array with `random` variable so, it's always take `undefined` as value

**3.** You forget to call `generateRandom()` method.

Here down is code:

```js
var randomcity = ["Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Ağrı"," Aksaray", "Amasya", "Ankara", "Antalya", "Ardahan", "Artvin", "Aydın", "Balıkesir", "Bartın", "Batman", "Bayburt", "Bilecik", "Bingöl", "Bitlis", "Bolu", "Burdur", "Bursa", "Çanakkale", "Çankırı", "Çorum", "Denizli", "Diyarbakır", "Düzce", "Edirne", "Elazığ", "Erzincan", "Erzurum", "Eskişehir", "Gaziantep", "Giresun", "Gümüşhane", "Hakkâri", "Hatay", "Iğdır", "Isparta", "İstanbul", "İzmir", "Kahramanmaraş", "Karabük", "Karaman", "Kars", "Kastamonu", "Kayseri", "Kilis", "Kırıkkale", "Kırklareli", "Kırşehir", "Kocaeli", "Konya", "Kütahya", "Malatya", "Manisa", "Mardin", "Mersin", "Muğla", "Muş", "Nevşehir", "Niğde", "Ordu", "Osmaniye", "Rize", "Sakarya", "Samsun", "Şanlıurfa", "Siirt", "Sinop", "Sivas", "Şırnak", "Tekirdağ", "Tokat", "Trabzon", "Tunceli", "Uşak", "Van", "Yalova", "Yozgat", "Zonguldak"]
var random;
function generateRandom () {
    random = randomcity[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomcity.length)];
    document.getElementById('txtcity').value = random;    
}

generateRandom();
```

```html
<label>City: </label>
<input id='txtcity' value = ''/>
```

Comment: Thank you to each and every one of you